# Codeigniter cannot call ajax function

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to validate a sign up form using ajax to check the availability of user input in a database. I'm using some code I found on a tutorial site but can't get it to work.

http://www.99points.info/2010/07/codeigniter-tutorial-check-usernameemail-availablity-using-jquer-in-codeigniter/

I'm using codeigniter framework, my php is ok but I know little of jQuery/js syntax

View:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    /// make loader hidden in start
    $('#Loading').hide();    
    $('#email').blur(function()
        {
        var a = $("#email").val();
        var filter = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
        // check if email is valid
        if(filter.test(a))
            {
            // show loader 
            $('#Loading').show();
            $.post("<?php echo base_url()?>signup/check_email_availablity", {
            email: $('#email').val()
            },
            function(response)
                {
                //#emailInfo is a span which will show you message
                $('#Loading').hide();
                setTimeout("finishAjax('Loading', '"+escape(response)+"')", 400);
                });
        return false;
        }
});
function finishAjax(id, response){
  $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
  $('#'+id).fadeIn();
}
</script>
```

So the ajax code does nothing the only thing I can see that's amiss is in the chrome developer tools console giving an error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Is there some syntax error messing it up?

Am I missing some library/helper that I need to load in codeigniter?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem (at least) is in the `<?php echo base_url()?>`

You forgot `;` and no space before closing php tag.

change to :

```
<?php echo base_url(); ?>
```